# Why is my D90 taking only black photos?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d90

I was taking photos, and two were normal but then all the rest were coming out as completely black pictures. The camera appears to be taking the photo normally.  I have tried multiple shutter speeds, aperture settings, flash — even to try to just have a completely overexposed picture — and still, black.

They are actual pictures being recorded on my memory card as I can see them on the viewfinder as well as on the computer. I have tried different lenses and checked the sensor area and I cannot figure out what is wrong. I have looked everywhere to see if anything has been posted like this before or if it was in my user manual and still nothing. Help!

Comment: you should remove the lenscap :) (couldn't resist)...

Comment: and if it's not on the lens, you should take the camera to a qualified Nikon service center (with the lens) and have them check it out.

Comment: Does it _sound_ normal? Can you see the viewfinder black out for an instant when you click the shutter?

Answer (score 10):

If the pictures are all pure black (as in every pixel is colour 0,0,0) then that sounds like a fairly terminal electronics problem.

If you're getting black photos where noise is visible if you boost the exposure on the computer then it sounds like a shutter malfunctioning. If the viewfinder is not blacking out momentarily it could be the mirror is staying down blocking the exposure. If the mirror is flipping up then the shutter may not be opening. Note there are two shutter curtains, if one is stuck it's possible that the sensor is never exposed to light, even if the shutter is still making a normal sound (indicating that *something* is moving).

If it's a mirror/shutter problem then it's fixable, though you should get an estimate first and compare that to the value of a used D90 to work out if it's economical before getting the work done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I took my D90 to a camera store, they are going to call me with a quote.